# Using html() as an attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I am trying to select an element in the list depending on its html content. I was hoping to do something like `$('li[html="something"]')`, but of course html isn't an attribute. Is there an equivalent set based operation?

I could of course iterate all the elements in the list using `$.each()`, but it seems to me it will be quite a lot slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try the :contains() selector

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
$("li:contains('something')")
```

For an exact match (from the link above):

```
$.expr[":"].contains = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
    return $.trim($(obj).html()) == meta[3];
}
```

Usage:

```
$("li:contains('john')")
```

This will only match `<li>John</li>`, not `<li>A. John</li>`, neither `<li>John 6</li>`... just `<li>John</li>`!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `contains()` selector:

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: That doesn't quite cut it, because that doesn't guarantee uniqueness, i.e. for `<ul><li>some</li><li>something</li></ul>` using `$('li:contains("some")')` both will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but the correct solution requires building on that using $.extend. Here is what I came up with:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    'hasHtml': function(elem, i, attr) {
        return ($(elem).html() == attr[3]);
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work in IE 6 because $(elem).html() returns "john ". You need to call trim() function as in my answer to make this work in all cases. Unfortunately a lot of people still use IE 6

Comment: Don't count on that. It is not the same as running it in IE6 standalone. Unfortunately, I work in a Bank. Nothing wrong with that per se, but the majority of workstations in most banks are still IE 6. They have a very slooow upgrade cycle. It doesn't work on any of our machines here without the trim. It doesn't do any harm to put it in. Good luck.

Comment: True. We don't actually support or develop for IE6, so it's not an issue. But I'll accept your answer for completeness.

Comment: Appreciate that. Wish I didn't have to either. :)